# How to pass words to an array not single characters - Python

Tags: python

So I'm reading in a txt file in python and want to get a list of all the words in the file. I am doing so by this method.

```
def parse_in(file_location, input_name):
    all_words = []
    with open(file_location + input_name,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                all_words += word
    f.close
    return all_words
```

Instead of all_words returning actual words it returns a list of single characters like `['A', 'B', 'C']` and so on.

But when debugging I can see that the variable word is an actual word and not just characters. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `f.close` does nothing. Your adding a sequence (string) to another sequence (a list), so you get a sequence thats the combination of both sequences. Use `list.append`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
all_words.append(word)
```

instead of

```
all_words += word
```

If you use `+=` then `word` is treated as a sequence, so the individual characters are each appended to the list.

Alternatively, you can use `+=`, and simplify your loop to:

```
for line in f:
    all_words += line.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def parse_in(file_location, input_name):
    all_words = []
    with open(file_location + input_name,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            all_words += line.split()
    return all_words
```

Answer (score 0):

`all_words += word` extends the list `all_words` with the items in `word`. As `word` is a string, the characters are appended, as if you had iterated through it with `for`.

Use `all_words.append(word)` to append the word to the word list.

Answer (score 0):

if you use context manager you do not need to close the file, and for simplicity you could just read entire file and just use split method

```
def parse_in(file_location, input_name):
    all_words = []
    with open(file_location + input_name,'r') as f:
        all_words = f.read().split()

    return all_words
```